# R progress bar for reading multiple csv (tsv) files

Tags: r

is there any way to display a progress bar for importing multiple csv-files.
here is the import code:
List all fiels to be imported:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*\\.tsv$") 
temp
```

Specific columns will be imported:

```
test_data <- lapply(temp,function(x){
  read.csv(file = x,
           sep ="\t",
           fill = TRUE,
           quote='', 
           header = FALSE 
  )[ ,c(287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 304, 370, 661, 662, 812, 813,994, 995, 1002)]
}
)
```

How can I monitor the current progress status?
I just did find some advices for loops, but not for importing files

Comment: `read_csv` from the `readr` package will give you a progress bar.

Comment: Got error message for read_csv: Fehler in readr::read_csv(file = x, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, quote = "",  : 
  unbenutzte Argumente (unused argument) (sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, header = FALSE)

Comment: The arguments are different for `read_csv`, but it looks looks you found your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `progress` library:

```
library(progress)                                                      # add
temp <- list.files(pattern="*\\.tsv$") 
pb <- progress_bar$new(format = " progress [:bar] :percent eta: :eta", # add
                       total = length(temp), clear = FALSE, width= 60) # add
test_data <- lapply(temp,function(x){
  pb$tick()                                                            # add
  read.csv(file = x,
           sep ="\t",
           fill = TRUE,
           quote='', 
           header = FALSE 
  )[ ,c(287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 304, 370, 661, 662, 812, 813,994, 995, 1002)]
})
```

I have marked the lines you need to add with a `# add` comment. There is also a native `R` progress bar which you can use, but I find the `progress` version more readable, configurable and easy to use.

Comment: the warning is related to your locale and not to the progress bar, what's the length of temp in your case?